# Is there any way to go back to previous state on hitting standard CANCEL button in SuiteFlow?

Tags: workflow, netsuite

In our workfow, flow is going to next state(in edit mode) on hitting a button.
Is it possible to navigate to the previous state(or any other state) on hitting standard CANCEL button?

I tried below on transition condition:

TRANSITION ON: `after record submit` and `before record submit`

EVENT TYPES: `Cancel`

but workflow doesnt go to the required state. Any suggestion can anyone give me please.

Comment: What Record Type are you working with, and are you in Edit or View mode when you hit the CANCEL button?

Comment: it's a custom record And I'm in edit mode when I click the CANCEL button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Cancel" user event type is only applicable to certain record types (typically transactions).  An example of where it applies is a sales order in "Pending Approval" status, where you will see a button or an entry under the Actions menu (depending on how the form is configured), saying "Cancel Order".  This will set the order status to "Cancelled" and fire the "Cancel" event.  Note that this button or action-menu entry is only visible when the order is in View mode - it is not shown in Edit mode.

Take note that there is also a "Cancel" button on every form, when in Edit mode.  This is used to cancel any inputs made to the form, and return to the previous page (for example: if you're on a record in View mode and click Edit and then click Cancel, the Cancel button returns you to View mode).  This Cancel button does not change the record, and does not fire any user events.